# Support for ipad size in Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, ipad

I have successfully completed iPhone development using Auto Layout.

Thanks to Auto Layout, UI is displayed normally on all iPhones.

However, if I run it on the iPad, the UI will not break, but the screen will be small.

I have no idea what to do to support iPad size in storyboard or build settings.

If I want my app to respond to iPad size, what method should I use specifically?

I am using Xcode 10 and Swift 4.

Comment: Check your target settings. Sounds like you are not supporting universal devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Select your project in Xcode, then use the General tab. It's under the sections on Identity and Signing.

Answer (score 2):

1) Select constraint that you need to update for iPad.

2) Click on + sign to the left of "Constant" value
 [image]

3) Select Width and Height - Regular which conforms to iPad in portrait and landscape orientation and set your values

4) Now when your select iPad second value will be applied to your layout. [image: New layout constraints on search field height]

Also you can vary font for different devices:
[image: Different font settings for iPad]

Every settings that has + sign on the left can be vary for different screen sizes and orientations. You can read great tutorial about variations on
[Ray Wenderlich web site](https://www.raywenderlich.com/492-adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-11-getting-started)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use "Vary for Traits" when editing the storyboard. You can then adjust the layout for the different sizes of iPad.

[image: XCode screenshot]

As stated in the comments above, check your deployment info also to ensure it's set to "Universal".

Comment: Press Command+1. At the top of your project structure you'll find your project name with blue project icon. Select it. There will be "Identity", "Signing", "Development info" update it "Devices" to "Universal"