# The size of app doesn't change when i run on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator

[image]I have an app that runs perfectly on all iPhone devices, But when I run in iPad it gives me likes this.

Am I missing anything, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: That's an iPhone-only app. You want a Universal app.

Comment: Yaa I even changed it to universal, it's still showing same

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Support for ipad size in Swift 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53097843/support-for-ipad-size-in-swift-4)

Comment: Do you have a launch screen storyboard in place?

Comment: No Launch screen

Comment: You need a launch screen file (storyboard) if you want to support all screen sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to set your App as `Universal` in:

General -> Deployment info -> Devices

[image]